# Vectorized assignment for numpy array with repeated indices (d[i,j,i,j] = s[i,j])

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

How can I set

```
d[i,j,i,j] = s[i,j]
```

using "NumPy" and without for loop?

I've tried the follow:

```
l1=range(M)
l2=range(N)
d[l1,l2,l1,l2] = s[l1,l2]
```

Comment: What about values for `d[1,2,3,4]` (so with `d[i,j,k,l]` where `k != i` and `l != j`)?

Comment: All the rest values are 0

Comment: What's the shape of `d`? Is it initialized with zeros? If so, what's the shape of it?

Comment: And I would be interested in the shape of `s`. Is it `(M, N)` with the `M` and `N` you used for your `range`s?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) (creating the broadcasted indices with [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html)):

```
d[np.ix_(l1,l2)*2] = s[np.ix_(l1,l2)]
```

The first time the indices have to be duplicated (you want `[i, j, i, j]` instead of just `[i, j]`) that's why I multiplied the `tuple` returned by `np.ix_` with 2.

---

For example:

```
>>> d = np.zeros((10, 10, 10, 10), dtype=int)
>>> s = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)
>>> l1 = range(3)
>>> l2 = range(5)
>>> d[np.ix_(l1,l2)*2] = s[np.ix_(l1,l2)]
```

And to make sure that the correct values were assigned:

```
>>> # Assert equality for the given condition
>>> for i in l1:
...     for j in l2:
...         assert d[i, j, i, j] == s[i, j]

>>> # Interactive tests
>>> d[0, 0, 0, 0], s[0, 0]
(0, 0)
>>> d[1, 2, 1, 2], s[1, 2]
(12, 12)
>>> d[2, 0, 2, 0], s[2, 0]
(20, 20)
>>> d[2, 4, 2, 4], s[2, 4]
(24, 24)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, that would be same as creating a `2D` array of shape `(m*n, m*n)` and assigning the values from `s` into the diagonal places. To have the final output as `4D`, we just need a reshape at the end. That's basically being implemented below -

```
m,n = s.shape
d = np.zeros((m*n,m*n),dtype=s.dtype)
d.ravel()[::m*n+1] = s.ravel()
d.shape = (m,n,m,n)
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
# @MSeifert's solution
def assign_vals_ix(s):    
    d = np.zeros((m, n, m, n), dtype=s.dtype)
    l1 = range(m)
    l2 = range(n)
    d[np.ix_(l1,l2)*2] = s[np.ix_(l1,l2)]
    return d

# Proposed in this post
def assign_vals(s):
    m,n = s.shape
    d = np.zeros((m*n,m*n),dtype=s.dtype)
    d.ravel()[::m*n+1] = s.ravel()
    return d.reshape(m,n,m,n)

# Using a strides based approach
def assign_vals_strides(a):
    m,n = a.shape
    p,q = a.strides

    d = np.zeros((m,n,m,n),dtype=a.dtype)
    out_strides = (q*(n*m*n+n),(m*n+1)*q)
    d_view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(d, (m,n), out_strides)
    d_view[:] = a
    return d
```

Timings -

```
In [285]: m,n = 10,10
     ...: s = np.random.rand(m,n)
     ...: d = np.zeros((m,n,m,n))
     ...: 

In [286]: %timeit assign_vals_ix(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.3 µs per loop

In [287]: %timeit assign_vals_strides(s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.37 µs per loop

In [288]: %timeit assign_vals(s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.13 µs per loop

In [289]: m,n = 20,20
     ...: s = np.random.rand(m,n)
     ...: d = np.zeros((m,n,m,n))


In [290]: %timeit assign_vals_ix(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 60.2 µs per loop

In [291]: %timeit assign_vals_strides(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 41.8 µs per loop

In [292]: %timeit assign_vals(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: It's also possible to do this with a non-contiguous input `d` with `numpy.lib.stride_tricks`, or by using `numpy.diagonal` twice. (`ravel()` might make a copy for a noncontiguous input.)

Comment: (Not quite the same flat, strided slice-assignment, but we can take a view of `d` shaped like `s` and slice-assign into that.)

Comment: Is it sensible to assume that the shape of `s` is `(m, n)` and `d` `(m*n,m*n)`? I assumed the problem here was a bit more general because in the comments he already said that ["All the rest values are 0"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855086/vectorized-assignment-for-numpy-array-with-repeated-indices-di-j-i-j-si-j/43855228#comment74745951_43855086) which means that the shapes don't necessarily have to match the `l1` and `l2`. Or am I misinterpreting your answer?

Comment: @user2357112 Good idea! Implemented and timed it. Doesn't look like its improving upon flattened view assignment though.

Comment: @MSeifert: It looks to me like that comment (and the one it's a reply to) are talking about elements at indices not of the form `i,j,i,j`, such as `1,2,3,4`.

Comment: @MSeifert The original code : `d[i,j,i,j] = s[i,j]` when iterated with `i = 1:m, j=1:n` won't assign into all values of `d`. That's why the comment asked what to do for the places in `d` that won't be assigned with that iterating code, to which OP replied those be zeros. Also, since, the code is iterating on `i` and `j`, generally it would be assumed that the limits to it are the shapes of arrays involved. Again, `d` could very well have a much bigger shape, but I am considering the general case here.

Comment: I'm not saying the approach is incorrect, but it's a special case (not the general case) where `(M, N)` actually represent the shape of `s`. While the `np.ix_` approach can handle arbitary (but valid) `l1` and `l2` indices